# GridView Sort from Search results instead of original data

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio, gridview

I am using VS2005 C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have a GridView which lists data from multiple sql queries.

At the end of the validation and checks, my table will contain a list of data retrieved from the sqls.

I will also be able to filter results (search function) base on `UserID`, `Username`, ... and so on.

I enabled sorting within the GridView to enable user to group same `UserID`, or 'Username`, or ... and so on.

After tried to filter results E.G. by `Username`, it will list only the records which has the `Username` I search for. And when I press *sorting* (column header), I would expect the GridView to sort only the results that is currently on the GridView.

However, when I press *sort* , it will drop back to the original long list of data instead of *sorting* my search results.

May I know is it possible to enable *sorting* on the current GridView only, rather than the whole list of data?

Thank you.

---

**EDIT:**

Simply saying, in GridView, am I able to sort my search results *only* instead of the whole list of data from the DB?

Comment: So you are kinda binding your Gridview to a List? grid.Itemsource = someList; ?

Comment: @Gero yes, just on the List on the page itself.

Comment: Why not make a 2nd list where you store your search results?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do the sort on the client-side. Use the [Tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) jquery plugin. [See this great example using asp.net gridview](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/705_Sorting_GridView_Using_JQuery_tableSorter_Plug_in.aspx).

Comment: obviously NOT. But using jquery will solve the "May I know is it possible to enable sorting on the current GridView only"

Comment: ic. I am using .Net 2.0. I saw on the site it says I need ASP.NET 4.0, true?

Comment: Not really. You can use .Net 2.0 (see this sample i adapted http://ge.tt/9YggaxA?c )

Answer (score 0):

In Silverlight i had a similar problem. I made a 2nd List where i would temporaly store the Search Elements and would bind that List to Grid. So i could perform operations, like sort, on the 2nd List and would not interfere with the main list, which contained all data unsorted. Thats how i quicksolved the problem.

Comment: hi Gero. I have tried to implement the search results to display on another webpage. However, when I press the header of the column to sort for that specific `searchResult` table, the table returns to full page after sorting. I have hovered my mouse over the header tab, and what I see is still javascript:_doPostBack(MainContent$GridView1,SortIssue) even though I have renamed my `GridView`. Do you have any solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

why don't use the DataTable.DefaultView? you can filter, sort, etc.